# How to remove an item after mutation from Apollo Cache?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I have a mutation which removes item from the database. I know that one of the possible ways to update the Apollo Cache is to specify an `update` function which will be called after success response. I also know that there're couple of ways to do it by using `cache.modify` and `cache.readQuery`/`cache.writeQuery` functions.

Examples provided by the Apollo documentations shows how to [remove an item from a list](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-removing-an-item-from-a-list). Unfortunately, provided example in an article shows how to update a nested property instead of removing entire object.

Could you help me please to understand how to correctly remove an entire item from the cache?

I use Apollo-Client v3+

This is my part of the code

```
export const REMOVE_ITEM_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation RemoveItem($itemId: String!) {
    removeItem(input: {
      itemId: $itemId
    }) {
      itemId # Returns an id of successfully deleted object
    }
  }
`
  

const [removeItem, { loading }] = useMutation(
  REMOVE_ITEM_MUTATION,
  {
    update: (cache, result) => {
      // How to use cache.modify? 
    },
    onError: (error) => { /*...*/ },
    onCompleted: (value) => { /*...*/ }
  }
)
```

P.S. I also confused if `cahce.modify` function can replace `cache.readQuery` and `cache.writeQuery`? I treat it like a new way of modifying the cache starting from Apollo Client 3. Am I right?

Comment: Answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713628/8230784